# How to conjugate "passé composé" with "vous" for movement verbs?

Tags: grammaire, participe-passé, passé-composé

I have seen in some books that an "s" is used in their conjugation. For example "vous est partis". But isn't it the case that "vous" refers to a singular noun ? What should i write in the exam if the teacher simply wants me to list out the conjugation of verb, the one with 's' or without 's'?

Answer (score 1):

When the past participle requires an agreement, this agreement should follow the logic, i.e. agree with the person(s) is applies to. It is only guessable without context when *il/elle/ils/elles* are used.

> *Je suis parti / partie
>
>   Tu es parti / partie
>
>   Il est parti
>
>   Elle est partie
>
>   On est parti / partie / partis / parties
>
>   Nous sommes (parti / partie)<sup>1</sup> / partis / parties
>
>   Vous êtes parti / partie / partis / parties
>
>   Ils sont partis
>
>   Elles sont parties*

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Very rare</sub>

Answer (score 0):

No, all that is quite wrong; the only possibility  **in the plural** is this:

> vous êtes partis.

Use a conjugation site, much information will be given you when you need it; there are several but here is a good one: [Le Monde](https://conjugaison.lemonde.fr/conjugaison/).

For the agreement when "vous" is the so called "vous de politesse" (only one person) there is no agreement (no s, [see this](http://grammaire.reverso.net/4_2_22_nous_vous.shtml)).

> vous êtes parti

Comment: so , if teacher asked to list out conjugation of a movement verb in passe compose , I should assume by default vous refers to plural ?

Comment: I forgot one detail in your question; you speak about verbs of movement but the type of verb doesn't matter at all; usually in France when people list the forms of the conjugation they neglect the second person plural a form of politeness and so list only 6 forms, 3 singular forms and 3 plural forms; however it is not forbidden to list the 7th form, in particular in the present case where spelling is different. If you do so it's a good idea to label this form as for instance "seconde personne de politesse".